# NSError *error; vs NSError *error = nil;

Tags: ios, nserror

I developed an ios app that had a:

```
NSError *error;
```

instead of:

```
NSError *error = nil;
```

It worked fine in while I was debugging in the simulator and debugging on the device while connected.  The moment I archived it and sent it into TestFlight to deploy for testing, I started getting **Unknown Signal** errors coming up in the crash log.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you have an uninitialized pointer. It does not crash as long as you get lucky, but using such pointers is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @daSn0wie When in doubt, log the address of the uninitialized variable right after declaring it. `NSLog(@"error: %p", error);`

Answer (score 3):

To clarify on dasblinkenlights answer, this is declaring a variable:

```
NSError *error;
```

... and this is declaring AND assigning a variable

```
NSError *error = nil;
```

When you use it the first way and try to access it without ever setting it to something, the value it is pointing at is known as "garbage" It is a pointer to some other stack of memory, and accessing it will almost always make your app crash. Thus, it is always best practice to assign a value to your variable as above, or shortly after.

Comment: One should not access an `NSError` var unless there is an error, generally by the method returning an error status. The APIs do not guarantee the value of the error var if there is no error. One can not rely that just because the var was set to nil and changed by the call that there was an error. So, setting it to nil does no harm nor good.

Comment: It really depends on which API he is using.

Comment: From the Apple docs on `NSError`: "In general, a method should signal an error condition by—for example—returning NO or nil rather than by the simple presence of an error object." Relying on a returned error code will always be safe, relying on an `NSError` object may or may not be safe. It is a choice.

Comment: The original poster never specified an Apple API. Making assumptions about his intentions is foolish.

Comment: With ARC, this is all irrelevant anyway.  By default, variables are assigned to nil upon their creation.

Comment: If we pass the address of nil into NSError ** parameter, when we access NSError later on, isn't this the same as accessing a nil?

Comment: sending a message to nil in objective-c does not crash. [nil anything] return nil.